# mybatis cursor cannot solve memory issue

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am using spring 2 and mybatis cursor to minimize the impact out of memory when selecting and process > 100k records at once, but I am not sure I am doing the right thing.

Mapper:

```
@SelectProvider(type = provider.class, method = "retrieveTx")
Cursor<TxModel> retrieveTx();
```

DAO:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<TxModel> retrieveTx() {
    Iterator<TxModel> iterator = mapper.retrieveTx().iterator();
    List<TxModel> actualList = new ArrayList<>();
    iterator.forEachRemaining(actualList::add);
    return actualList;
}
```

Using it :

```
List<TxModel> txs = dao.retrieveTx()
for (TxModel tx: txs) {
  ....
}
```

Anyone can suggest what I am doing is right? Because I felt that this method doesn't solve my problem when the db records is at 6 digits.

Comment: You are supposed to 'use' each object while iterating the result in the `retrieveTx()` method.
If you store all objects into a `List`, the list may occupy a lot of memory no matter how you retrieve the objects, you know.

Comment: understood. @ave